# PHP mysqli_stmt_bind_result with mysqli union

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I'm trying to create a `UNION query`, so I can get data from two tables (same DB) and later on I'm trying to pull that data with `mysqli_bind_result()`, but I get an error:

> mysqli_stmt_bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number

Here is my code:

```
$sql = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
if(mysqli_stmt_prepare($sql, "(SELECT `naslov`, `id_lang` FROM `naslovi` WHERE `id_vijesti` = ?) UNION ALL (SELECT `text`, `id_lang` FROM `tekstovi` WHERE `id_vijesti` = ?)")) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, "ii", $id, $id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($sql, $naslov, $id_lang1, $text, $id_lang2);    
    $vijest = array();

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($sql)) {
        echo $naslov;
        if($id_lang1 == $id_lang2) {
            $vijest[] = array($naslov, $text, $id_lang1);
        }

    }

    mysqli_stmt_close($sql);
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: is there a fix for that, I mean I can do 2 separate querys but I think using union is better :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that the numbers of variables don't match. An UNION query merges all the columns from the inner queries.

I think you're looking for a JOIN query here. Take a look at this page: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Edit: added an example

```
"SELECT 
    `naslovi`.`naslov`, `naslovi`.`id_lang`, `tekstovi`.`text`, `tekstovi`.`id_lang` AS tekstovi_id_lang 
    FROM `naslovi` JOIN `tekstovi` 
    ON `naslovi`.`id_vijesti` = `tekstovi`.`id_vijesti` 
    WHERE `naslovi`.`id_vijesti` = ?"
```

Comment: Join is not it, the identifier is from another table so I can use join them. id_vijesti comes from table vijesti and in tables tekstovi and naslovi I have field id_vijesti on which I take and merge them...

Comment: I know you use the same identifier, but that doesn't mean you cannot use JOIN. You want the data of both tables in the same rows. JOIN does that, while UNION gives you the data of both tables in seperate rows. Just give it a try, I've updated my answer.